# How to count occurrences of a column value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

my Query :

```
SELECT 
 max(if(`field_name`='your-name', `field_value`, null )) AS 'Name',
 max(if(`field_name`='your-email', `field_value`, null )) AS 'email',
 max(if(`field_name`='your-subject', `field_value`, null )) AS 'subject'


FROM Complaints 
WHERE `form_name` = 'Complaint'  
GROUP BY `submit_time`;
```

and the table look like that

```
+---------+---------------+---------+
|  Name   |     email     | Subject |
+---------+---------------+---------+
| Mike AA | test@test.com | test    |
| John    | a@test.com    | w       |
| Mike AA | test@test.com | zzzz    |
+---------+---------------+---------+
```

I am trying to add new column for count where value name is the same
so to be like this.
group records where "Name is the same"

```
+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
|  Name   |     email     | Subject | Number of Complaint |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
| Mike AA | test@test.com | test    |                   2 |
| John    | a@test.com    | w       |                   1 |
+---------+---------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Your query doesn't return the columns `Name`, `email`, and `Subject`.  I'm a little lost on what you are trying to do or on the relevance of your sample query.

Comment: I'm confused as to what value should be in `Subject` in your desired result. Random pick?

Comment: I edited my questions. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT name, email, min(Subject) as Subject, count(*) as NumComplaint
FROM `contactus`  c
WHERE `form_name` = 'Complaint'  
GROUP BY name, email;
```